# In Mercurial, how can I see revisions pushed to a repo in the last 24 hours?

Tags: mercurial

I have a Mercurial repository that several people push to from their own, local repositories. I'd like to be able to query this central repository for all changes that **arrived at that repository** in the last 24 hours, notably **not just** changes that were **committed** in the last 24 hours.

The *hg log --date* option doesn't do what I need. It only refines the selection based on the date of commit. So, *hg log --date -1* gets me revisions committed since yesterday, but not revisions committed, say, three days ago, but only **pushed to this repo** today.

If I can find the revision number (or id) of the oldest revision arriving at the repo less than 24 hours ago, that would do the trick; but I can't see anything — even in *hg help revsets* — that looks like it'll work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [pushlog](http://kenai.com/projects/sonichg/pages/Pushlog), an extension to Mercurial that you configure server-side.

Basically you install the requisite files, and configure your server repository hooks to call into pushlog on each push, and then the script will log whenever someone pushes to that repository.

Unfortunately I don't know more about it than what's on that page, I asked on the IRC channel of Mercurial and got that name there.

You can see an example of the log here: [calc pushlog](http://sonichg.zspin.com/hgview.cgi/calc/pushlog).

Additionally, there are web systems you can use that contains such logs. Here's what my [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) log looks like after todays changes.

[image: Kiln activity log]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to [pushlog](http://kenai.com/projects/sonichg/pages/Pushlog). It doesn't exactly meet my needs — what I'd really like is a way to do this retrospectively, rather than just "going forward" — but it sounds like a useful item to have in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built in method to do this, but you could get that information in a roundabout way. Write a script to clone your main repo each day, and name it accordingly; say `project1-2011-4-31`, `project1-2011-5-1\`. Then it's a simple matter of seeing what is incoming from one to the other:

```
cd %projectdirectory%\dateclones
cd project1-2011-3-25
hg incoming ..\project1-2011-5-1
```

Would give you all changes pushed between when `project1-2011-3-25` was cloned and `project1-2011-5-1` was cloned.

Comment: You don't need to clone the entire repo each time. Just use `hg pull` repeatedly. It will tell you how many changesets it adds to the local repo.

Comment: That gives me an interesting idea! I do actually have a daily clone of the repo going back several months. (We make the clone as the first step in our daily build process, and there's never been any reason to remove the old clones from the disk.) Going forward, I can make the daily build add a tag at the tip of the tree; then my query can just `hg log` today's tag vs yesterday's. For history, it would be pretty easy to iterate through all the old clones, find the tip rev in each, and tag it.

Comment: Tags are normally in history (adding a tag creates a commit), so anyone attempting @TimRuddick's solution should consider using the `-l` argument to `hg tag`, which makes them local and out-of-history instead.