# How to see time when patch was pushed in tortoiseHg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

We're using TortoiseHg 2.1.4 right now.

Our workflow looks something similar like this:

- dev1 creates change in baseline, exports patch via tortoiseHg
- dev1 gives patch to dev2 for review
- if review is ok, patch gets to a merge guy dev3, who then backports it

Problem: the time shown in tortoiseHg is the time of local patch creation/commit by dev1, but we want to see, in tortoiseHg, when the patch was pushed to baseline by dev3.

If there is a way to get the info via command line, that would work too, but adding the info to TortoiseHg would be better. Any ideas?

### Edit

This is a duplicate of [In Mercurial, how can I see revisions pushed to a repo in the last 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5851096), I misinterpreted the question there the first time. The answer there (serverside plugin only) sucks a bit, but anyway.

Comment: Nope, that’s basically it. You can also easily run it on your own computer by the way using `hg serve`. But the push-information is not distributed I guess.

Comment: Push information can't be distributed. Which push to which repo do you log? It's a concept that doesn't work unless the answer is all push/pulls to all repos. Then that's potentially a lot of information. What time did this commit land in the local repo is a valid question though, along with where did it come from, how did it get here, etc.

Comment: Just change workflow and use merges (two or more named branches) instead of patches, this way mergesets in default will have real time

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Mercurial, how can I see revisions pushed to a repo in the last 24 hours?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851096/in-mercurial-how-can-i-see-revisions-pushed-to-a-repo-in-the-last-24-hours)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Mercurial, how can I see revisions pushed to a repo in the last 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851096/in-mercurial-how-can-i-see-revisions-pushed-to-a-repo-in-the-last-24-hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a double of [In Mercurial, how can I see revisions pushed to a repo in the last 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5851096/830213), misinterpreted the question there the first time. Can be closed.